# How to JSON.parse() deserialize a JSON.stringify serialized object which contains a stringified object?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, json-deserialization, stringify

In Chrome console, I type:

```
JSON.stringify({a:{a:'{"a":"a"}'}})
```

I get the output:

```
"{"a":{"a":"{\"a\":\"a\"}"}}"
```

And I try to deserialize by:

```
JSON.parse('{"a":{"a":"{\"a\":\"a\"}"}}')
```

I get the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token a(…)
```

How can I deserialize the original object?

[image]

Comment: if you're going to do it in the console, you have to escape " and \ like so `JSON.parse("{\"a\":{\"a\":\"{\\\"a\\\":\\\"a\\\"}\"}}")`

Answer (score 2):

OK, I got the trick...

Escape the backslash '\', this works:

```
JSON.parse('{"a":{"a":"{\\"a\\":\\"a\\"}"}}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use from variables:

```js
var str = JSON.stringify({
  a: {
    a: '{"a":"a"}'
  }
});
console.log(str); //{"a":{"a":"{\"a\":\"a\"}"}}
console.log(JSON.parse(str));  //original object
console.log(JSON.parse('{"a":{"a":"{\"a\":\"a\"}"}}')); //error
```